# passing a string to a function that has white space

Tags: bash

Please help me with the below functionality. I need to pass a function in the form of an argument to another function. In the second function one of the parameter has space in the string.

```
function funct_1
{       
        echo $1
        echo $2
        ${3}
}

function funct_2
{
    echo $1
    echo $2
    echo $3
}

funct_1 first second 'funct_2 first second "first second"'
```

Expected Result -

```
first 
second
first
second
first second
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . The explanation helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `eval`:

```
function funct_1
{
        echo $1
        echo $2
        eval ${3}
}

function funct_2
{
    echo $1
    echo $2
    echo $3
}

funct_1 first second 'funct_2 first second "first second"'
```

Comment: Perfectly worked. Thanks for the quick answer. With the -x option I did understand what was actually happening and eval did the trick. Thanks again